# SWIFT: Quick cumulation of a lot of strings

Tags: arrays, string, performance, swift

I'm saving the begining of a lot of words:

```
var n = 2
var a = [String]()
for w in words {
     let part = prefix(w,n)
     if !contains(a, part) {
          a.append(part)
     }
}
```

For some milion words, this takes a lot of time. Is there any quick build-in solution of String/Array/Set ... to do this faster?

EDIT: Thanks to your hints, I could combine these ideas to a much better performance:

```
let words2 = words.map{prefix($0, n)}
var a = [String]()
var last = ""
for w in words2 {
    if w != last {
        a.append(w)
    }
    last = w
}
```

First it creates a 2-Character-Array. And in the loop I can simply compare the item to the previous one without any further string operations! Seems to be great. Any more advanced swift improvements?

Comment: One improvement could be to use a `Set` for the variable `a`, because `contains` on an `Array` could take a very long time, but it's O(1) in sets.

Comment: Great. This improves speed. I tested it.

Comment: @DánielNagy I assume `contains` in `Set` is faster than in `Array` because the OP already tested it. But can you give a documentation where it says the complexity is O(1)? Interpolation search averages O(log log n) while binary's is O(log n).

Comment: @ZoffDino I don't have a Swift related documentation, however, here is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So the `words` array is already sorted?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned that: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no guarantee that the `words` array is sorted, I would implement the following solution:

```
let prefixesSet = Set(words.map { prefix($0, length) })
```

### Analysis

Given `n`: `words.count`

The invocation of `map` requires time `O(n)`
I don't know how the `initializer` of `Set` is implemented. I can imagine a couple of scenarios:

1. The `initializer` does sort the input array in time `O(n log n)` and then add each element to the `Set` discarding duplicates `O(n)` (that after the sort are contiguous).
   **Total time of this scenario: O(n log n)**
2. Each word is added to the `Set` and indexed using an `hash map` where the key is the `hashValue` of the word itself. Here the efficiency is inversely proportional to the collisions. With collision I mean 2 distinct words that happen to have the same `hashValue`.
   However I except Cocoa to have a pretty good implementation of `hashValue` for strings so I think in this case the time could be close to **O(n)**.

### Conclusion

As I previously said, this apply if you have no guarantee that `words` is sorted. On the other hand, if `words` is sorted I think your second block of code represents the best approach. It only requires time **O(n)**.